# communicate via serial on android in xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, uwp

I am developing a cross-platform app in Xamarin to be used on windows and android.  In both apps I want to be able to access the serial port on the tablet so I am creating an abstract interface that I will implement for each platform.  I know how to access the serial port in a UWP app but how would I go about doing this on the android platform? I have already tried installing the Xamarin usb serial for android package from NuGet but it doesn't seem to be compatible with .NET 4.5. Are there any other methods for communicating via serial on android in Xamarin (C#)?

Comment: Do you want the usb communication or COM port? For usb there is available apis, for com port, you may need to use JNI to create a so lib.

Comment: I want to be able to use a COM port.  Is there functionality for this in Xamarin.Android?

Comment: as far as I know, we need to use JNI and implement the function in c/c++ in so lib.